# How to add dynamic Columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using following query to do this

```
select (Col_A + Col_B) Foo,
       (Col_C + Col_D) Bar,
       (Col_A + Col_B + Col_C + Col_D) FooBar from Table1
```

But is there a way like to do like this

```
select (Col_A + Col_B) Foo,
       (Col_C + Col_D) Bar,
       (Foo + Bar) FooBar from Table1
```

it gives Error

```
'Invalid Column Foo'
'Invalid Column Bar'
```

How to solve this?

Comment: There is logical processing of query, basicaly you can use new column names just in `Order by` statement http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial solution is to use `with` construction:

```
with query as (
  select (Col_A + Col_B) Foo,
         (Col_C + Col_D) Bar
    from Table1)

select Foo,
       Bar,
       Foo + Bar
  from query
```

Comment: @Nikhil Agrawal: it has name CTE in MS SQL, but "with" works (with some restrictions) in Oracle, Postgre as well

Answer (score 0):

Afaik those columns you're referring to don't exist by those names yet.

You can of course try the following instead:

```
SELECT *, (Foo + Bar) FooBar
FROM (select (Col_A + Col_B) Foo,
       (Col_C + Col_D) Bar
     from Table1) SRC
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL parses the FROM before SELECT so you need to add your alias in your FROM clause

```
SELECT Foo
      ,Bar
      ,Foo + Bar
FROM Table1
     CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT Col_A + Col_B AS Foo
               ,Col_C + Col_D AS Bar
     ) AS CA1
```